# Android Gradle - is use splits only for release possible?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I want use "splits" by "abi", but only for release build. Is this possible? I try use ext variable and variable by "def" also which is set to false by default. This variable is set to true in buildTypes for releaseWithLog (and release).

But I don't know how Gradle work, because when I add writeln() with test message to "debug", "releaseWithLog" and "release" and run build, all messages are in output, so this confirms me that variable "splitsEnabled" is set to true though I build for debug - and I expect value "false" for debug (and not using splits for debug therefore).

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion '20.0.0'
    ext {
        splitsEnabled = false
    }
    defaultConfig {
    ...
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            ...
        }
        releaseWithLog {
            ...
            splitsEnabled = true
        }
        release.initWith(releaseWithLog)
        release {
            ...
        }
    }
    ...
    splits {
        abi {
            println(splitsEnabled)
            enable splitsEnabled
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'armeabi'
            exclude 'x86_64', 'mips64', 'arm64-v8a', 'mips'
            universalApk true
        }
    }
    ...
```

Comment: Since `splits` is a peer of `buildTypes`, I suspect that splits cannot be done on a per-type basis, but I'll be happy to be proven wrong. But please bear in mind that `enable splitsEnabled` is run well before a build type is chosen. The statements in `build.gradle` are mostly building an object model. This is not an interpreted script. Only after the object model is built does Gradle start figuring out what the build type(s) are needed for the task(s) being run.

Comment: I'm interested too - would love to save build time and just build one split in Debug

Comment: I ended up reverting back to the old way of doing ABI builds to solve this issue!

https://twitter.com/silentnuke/status/619501266646003713

Answer (score 7):

You can solve this easily with a command line argument to Gradle, or the "Script parameters:" field for a Gradle task in Android Studio. I used -P to define 'dbgBld' symbol and used it for debug builds, e.g.:

```
gradle -PdbgBld installDebug
```

My build.gradle file has the following splits command:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable !project.hasProperty('dbgBld')
        reset()
        include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Now to build release I use:

```
gradle assembleRelease
```

The 'dbgBld' symbol is not defined, so the splits enable field resolves to true and I get 5 APK files. When building for debugging, the -PdbgBld is already saved in my Android Studio configuration and I get only one "fat" APK for debugging, which results in much faster debug builds.

Greg

Comment: Found this really useful

Comment: Is there a way to set this in Android Studio run/debug launch configuration?

Comment: @OrB I see that now my Android Studio run/debug launch configuration executes a "Grade-aware Make" command. I don't know where to edit any options for this one, but for building the actual Release build, you still need to execute 'gradle assembleRelease'. I would just reverse the condition and define something like releaseBld constant, to have 'gradle -PreleaseBld assembleRelease' and modify build.gradle accordingly.

Comment: What does reset() call do?

Comment: @scana: **reset** the list of densities to be included to an empty string _(this allows, in conjunctions with include, to indicate which one to use rather than which ones to ignore)_

Comment: Is there any way to do this without using the script parameter?  I'm hoping there is a programmatic way to detect if the build is doing a release or debug.

Comment: @MarkCarter - if there is a way, I have not found it so far. Maybe someone else will post a solution...