# Android product flavors are not considered when using CPU ABI split in build.gradle

Tags: android, apk, android-gradle-plugin, android-productflavors

I want to make APK split based on CPU ABI according to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits, however I want to split the APK only for a certain product flavor.

So my `build.gradle` file has the following product flavors `plain` and `market`. Actually I want the APK split to be performed when building `market` flavor.

```
android {
    productFlavors {
        plain {
        }
        market {
            splits {
                abi {
                    enable true
                    reset()
                    include 'armeabi', 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86', 'mips'
                    universalApk true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, when I invoke `gradle assemblePlainDebug` and `assembleMarketDebug`, both of them produces the multiple APK. Is there something wrong with the configuration above?

I'm using `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3`.

Comment: I reported this as a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=178606 So far there are no stars except by me. Please help starring that issue if you experience the same problem.

Answer (score 17):

I've been looking for a way to do this for a while and haven't found a solid solution. Something to do with the splits having to be run before resolving the buildTypes and productFlavors.

The [Android Gradle - is use splits only for release possible?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27964484/android-gradle-is-use-splits-only-for-release-possible) question had answer that I thought useful. It basically relies on a project property, passed in when building via the command line or continuous integration invironment, to set weather the split apk's option is enabled or not.

I used it like this:

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable project.hasProperty('splitApk')
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips', 'armeabi'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

and then depending on what falvour or build type you are building you can include:

```
./gradlew --project-prop splitApk assembleMarketDebug
```

This should then only enable the apk split when explicitly told too and should stay disabled for everything else.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it worked. I needed a flavor with C++ unit test to only build in X86 architecture.