# How to test if we are doing a release build in Gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I need to do some build operations only during release build to speed up the routine debug build. How to test, if I'm doing a release build in the `build.gradle` script?

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable /* CONDITION HERE ->  */ true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

I found an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32383285/952135), but I don't want to set build property, I prefer it to be automatic.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please try:

```
splits {
    abi {
        if (project.gradle.startParameter.taskNames.any { it.toLowerCase().contains('release') }) {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'x86', 'armeabi-v7a', 'mips'
            universalApk true
        } else {
            enable true
            reset()
            include 'armeabi-v7a'
            universalApk false
        }
    }
}
```

However, mind the fact that this configuration doesn't take task dependencies into account.
What I mean is a task may depend on some *release* task and even if it isn't passed via command line it might be executed.